# LoadError: dlopen while running bundle exec rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, therubyracer

After running bundle install successfully when I ran **bundle exec rake db:migrate** its gives me the error below

> LoadError:
> dlopen(/Users/animesh/Workspace/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.bundle,
> 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace
> '__ZN2v810ScriptData10PreCompileEPKci' -
> /Users/animesh/Workspace/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.bundle

**OS:** macOS Monetery 12.1

**Ruby version:** ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]

**Therubyracer Path:** /Users/animesh/Workspace/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3

**v8:**

> stable 9.9.115.8 (bottled) Google's JavaScript engine
> https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/v8/9.9.115.8
> (200 files, 44.5MB) *   Poured from bottle on 2022-04-09 at 10:38:00
> From:
> https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/v8.rb
> License: BSD-3-Clause
> ==> Dependencies Build: ninja ✘, python@3.10 ✘, llvm ✘
> ==> Requirements Build: Xcode >= 10.0 ✘
> ==> Analytics install: 2,098 (30 days), 9,117 (90 days), 42,731 (365 days) install-on-request: 2,064 (30 days), 8,940 (90 days), 41,598
> (365 days) build-error: 6 (30 days)

Comment: Remove `therubyracer` gem, and then do another `bundle install`?